# android - State based order of execution of activites

Tags: android

I want to create an app where there are few activities and layouts that are reused in the app in different orders.
So basically instead of putting if else in my code to find from where it was called and which activity should be called next I want to know if there is a cleaner way to do this.

Currently I am sending the state in intent for the activity to decide what is the next step for it.

1) login
2) books assigned - shows list of books I shud take 
3) Desk assigned - show the desk I shud go to
Some other process 
now the last screens are in the reverse order
3.10)
4) unassign desk
5) return books
6) logout

For 1 & 6, 2&5 and 3 & 4 I can use the same activity and layout and depending on from which activity I got the control I can decide the order. Like if the BooksActivity was called from Login I populate the screen with assign information and my next screen will be desk assign but if it was called from 3.10 I show unassign information and my next screen will be logout.

Comment: Looks like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9686797/how-to-change-value-of-textview-of-an-activity-depending-on-the-different-activi is similar to my question. But I was wondering if there is a better way to do it instead of using intents. Like some place to define the order of the activites

Comment: What's wrong with using intents?

Comment: There is nothing wrong but if I look at my activities in all of them i m doing the same stuff. 
If getExtra("STATE") == "home" then 
setText("Assign"); next Activity = Assign desk; else logout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is the simplest.

You can create a global controller to store the applications current state, and query it for the needed operations.

On a simple app such as yours this seems to be an overkill, but as states become more and more complex, or when you need to persistently store the app's state, the controller approach would begin to have an appeal.

Comment: Yes I want the app to be able to support more such states in future. So global controller can be as simple as storing the state in Shared Preferences and then reading it all the activites right ? But I will still have those if else in the code which I think I cannot get rid of if I want the same activity to be able to take 2 different paths.

Comment: In a global controller I meant something in the line of a singleton, which you will have to turn into a Service eventually.

This is the common approach. However eventually you will have to have a piece of code parsing the current state and deciding what path your Activity should take.
There are possible approaches to avoid complex "case" or "if" statements, but again - in a simple app such as yours, why bother with something fancy prone to bugs?

Comment: The if else is not only for selecting the next activity but also to populate the layout elements with different text. Well this app is more for a learning purpose so I would like to try something fancy :)

Comment: You could create seperate bean objects, containing the relevant texts and flows, and then have the controller dispatch the right bean to a "stupid" Activity that has almost no logic of its own.

Comment: Also - if you're satisfied with the discussion please mark the answer.